# Trouble with boolean expression comparing List<int[]> .get() function with array

Tags: java, arrays, list, for-loop, collections

I am trying to evaluate and return true given the following code. Why is  .get(i) not equal to int array? Intellisense hasn't picked up any compiling errors.

```
private static boolean isTravelled(List<List<int[]>> paths, int x, 
int y) {
    int[] arr = new int[]{x, y};
    boolean isTravelled = false;
    for (List<int[]> path : paths) {
        for (int i = 0; i < path.size(); i++) {
            if (path.get(i) == arr) {
                isTravelled = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return isTravelled;
}
```

I have tried creating a LinkedList to compare List path with.

```
List<int[]> arrL = new LinkedList<>();
int[] arr = new int[]{x, y};    
arrL.add(arr);

for(List<int[]> path : paths) {
     for (int i = 0; i < path.size(); i++) {
          if (path.get(i) == arrL.get(0)) {

          }
     }
}
```

[Variables List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBFtX.png)

I am expecting to change isTravelled to true, but the if statement never returns true.

Comment: You create `arr` at the beginning and only compare the identity, not it's contents. So it is never true.

Comment: I'm working on storing a temp array to hold the contents of path.get(i), maybe that will fix it.

Comment: It's also *much* better to use a for-each loop to iterate `path`; `get(int)` can be expensive for some lists (such as `LinkedList`). Finally, you can just `return true` from the middle of the loop if all you want to do is signal success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`path.get(i) == arr` - this is not how you compare arrays in java.

Change it to `Arrays.equals(path.get(i), arr)` as you want to compare the contents of the arrays, not their references.

Comment: Thanks! That did it. I knew I must have been referencing different objects in memory.